# merge object with nested properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to merge two object using JavaScript

**First**

```
{
    "user" : " Hari",
    "friend" : "Shiva",
    "friendList": ["Hanks"," Tom"," Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh"]
}
```

**second**

```
{
    "user" : "Hari",
    "friend" : " Shiva",
    "friendList" : ["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva",
                    " Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]
}
```

and form a single object:

**expected output**

```
{
    "user" : "Hari"
    "friend" : "Shiva",
    "friendList":[
        ["Hanks"," Tom","Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh"],
        ["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva"," Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]
     ]
}
```

Is it possible? I am sorry if it is wrong question....but I need to solve in this way and I do not have much idea about JavaScript.

Comment: Your objects appear to be invalid. Please verify their format.

Comment: I'm affraid your objects definitions are wrong

Comment: @bikas, I have edited your question to put the representation of the objects into a valid format. Please verify that it is what you desire. Feel free to revert the edit and/or change it to what you intend.

Comment: @bikas, Are you sure you want the `friendList` two have an array of two arrays? Or should it be merged into a single array containing all the members of the original two arrays? If so, should we check for duplicates and only put one of the duplicate names on the new full `friendList`?

Comment: @bikas, Also, are we first supposed to verify that the `user` matches in the first and second object prior to merging? Should we only merge when *both* the `name` and the `friend` match in both objects?

Comment: @Makyen, yes friend i want friendList have an array of two arrays and also i only want to merge when both the name and the friend match in  both objects..

Answer (score 0):

You can add from one array to anther like this

```
    var a={
    "user" : " Hari",
    "friend" : "Shiva",
    "friendList": ["Hanks"," Tom"," Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh"]
};
var b={
    "user" : "Hari",
    "friend" : " Shiva",
    "friendList" : ["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva",
                    " Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]
};
    b.friendList.concat(a.friendList);
```

you will get on b all the array of a+b...

you will not get this structure that you want. For my code you will get an array of strings from a and b, if you want this structure you need to change the result to be an object and not array.

also can see example from : [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will merge the objects as described in your question:

```js
var firstObject = {
    "user" : " Hari",
    "friend" : "Shiva",
    "friendList": ["Hanks"," Tom"," Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh"]
};
var secondObject = {
    "user" : "Hari",
    "friend" : " Shiva",
    "friendList" : ["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva",
                    " Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"],
};

function mergeMyObjectsIntoNew(first,second,copyFriendListArrayReference){
    //.trim() is needed in the compare here because example data has a leading space
    //  in secondObject.friend
    if(first.user.trim() === second.user.trim() 
        && first.friend.trim() === second.friend.trim()){
        var newObject={}; //The new object
        newObject.user = first.user;
        newObject.friend = first.friend;
        newObject.friendList = []; //Create new array
        if(copyFriendListArrayReference){
            //This copies references for the arrays in first.friendList and
            //  second.friendList into the array new.friendList.  These will be the
            //  same arrays as exists in first and second.  Changes to the contents
            //  of those arrays will affect the arrays in the newObject.
            newObject.friendList[0] = first.friendList; //add friendList from first
            newObject.friendList[1] = second.friendList; //add friendList from second
        }else{
            //This copies the string contents of the arrays in first.friendList and
            //  second.friendList into the array new.friendList.  These will NOT be the
            //  same arrays as exists in first and second.  Changes to the contents
            //  of those arrays will NOT affect the arrays in the newObject.
            //  This is the default behavior.

            //Copy contents of friendList from first
            newObject.friendList[0] = Array.from(first.friendList);
            //Copy contents of friendList from second
            newObject.friendList[1] = Array.from(second.friendList);
        }
        return newObject;
    }//implicit else due to 'return' in all if paths
    return null; //Indicate to caller that there was not a match.
}

//Get new merged object with copy of friendList
mergedObject = mergeMyObjectsIntoNew(firstObject,secondObject);

console.log(mergedObject);
```

### Comments

**Using multiple very similarly structured objects is, often, a bad idea**
It is, generally, not a good idea to use objects that have two different structures, unless you are keeping those objects distinctly separate. When you do have multiple structures for objects which you treat similarly (i.e. you use the same functions/methods to manipulate objects with both structures), all of your code has to account for each of the multiple structures. This can rapidly make your code much more complex and, potentially, more confusing than it would need to be if you did not have multiple structures for objects which you treat similarly.

In this case, you are wanting your result object to have a `friendList` property which is an array of arrays of strings whereas your source objects have a `friendList` property which is an array of strings. If you are going to use `mergeMyObjectsIntoNew` on both object structures, having the two different structures for the `friendList` property would require more logic in `mergeMyObjectsIntoNew`, if you want it to be able to operate on both types of object with the results you would, probably, expect.

For instance, the following code will not produce the result that you are probably expecting:

```
mergedFirstSecondObject = mergeMyObjectsIntoNew(firstObject,secondObject);
mergedthirdFourthObject = mergeMyObjectsIntoNew(firstObject,secondObject);

mergedFourObjects = mergeMyObjectsIntoNew(mergedFirstSecondObject,mergedthirdFourthObject);
```

This will produce an object that has a `friendList` property that is an array of arrays of arrays of strings. The `mergedFourObjects` object is structured like:

```
{
    "user" : " Hari",
    "friend" : "Shiva",
    "friendList": [
        [
            friendListArrayFromFirstObject,
            friendListArrayFromSecondObject
        ],
        [
            friendListArrayFromThirdObject,
            friendListArrayFromFourthObject
        ]
    ]
}
```

In your case, you are probably better off picking to always have the `friendList` property be only one or the other of an array of array of strings, or an array of strings.  Having the `friendList` property such that it might be either structure will significantly complicate your code everywhere you use these objects.

**Using a class would be the better approach to handling your objects**
If you are going to be using your objects in a larger project, it is probably a better idea to use a class for the object.  This would allow you to move things like comparing the objects and merging the objects into methods of the class (e.g. `MyObject.prototype.compare(second)` and `MyObject.prototype.merge(second)`. However, that is a discussion well beyond the scope of your question. If you want more information, I suggest you search for information about using object classes in JavaScript.